# Hook or event before a page gets cached

Tags: hooks, caching, event-subscribers

Is there a hook or event I can tie into before a page gets cached. I need a hook/event that I can call so that I can run some logic on the page that is about to be cached to tell Drupal if I want a particular page to actually get cached. This is a very specific use case to the website I'm working on.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to decide whenever a page should be cached from Drupal, you need to create a service that implements the [`\Drupal\Core\PageCache\ResponsePolicyInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21PageCache%21ResponsePolicyInterface.php/interface/ResponsePolicyInterface/8.6.x) interface and it's tagged *page_cache_response_policy*, as described in [Flexible page cache policy](https://www.drupal.org/node/2323571).

That page shows code that can be used as example. You can also use code that Drupal core actually implements, as example, like the code for the [node.page_cache_response_policy.deny_node_preview](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.services.yml/service/node.page_cache_response_policy.deny_node_preview/8.6.x) service.

The code implementing the service is quite simple. It becomes more complex basing on the logic you need to apply to decide when a page should be cached.

```
class DenyNodePreview implements ResponsePolicyInterface {

  /**
   * The current route match.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface
   */
  protected $routeMatch;

  /**
   * Constructs a deny node preview page cache policy.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface $route_match
   *   The current route match.
   */
  public function __construct(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
    $this->routeMatch = $route_match;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function check(Response $response, Request $request) {
    if ($this->routeMatch
      ->getRouteName() === 'entity.node.preview') {
      return static::DENY;
    }
  }

}
```